# EDATE minus 6 minus 6 is not same as -12

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

Is there some way to get `2014-06-30` minus 6 months to be `2013-12-31` rather than `2013-12-30` (i.e always end of month)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `=EOMONTH(F1,-F2)` instead of `EDATE`.  `EOMONTH` goes to the end of the month for a given month.  `-6` goes backward.